# Coordinate Change problem...

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t} v(x-ct+cs,s) ds 
\end{equation}
And,
\begin{equation}
v(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(x+ct-cs,s)ds
\end{equation}

I'll show that
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c} \int_{0}^{t}\int_{x-ct+cs}^{x+ct-cs} f(y,s)dyds
\end{equation}
I don't know how to change coordinate...

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the substitution, we have:
$$
u(x,t)=\int_0^t v(x-ct+cs,s) \, ds = \int_0^t \int_0^s f(x-ct+2cs-cr,r) \,dr\, ds 
$$
Now the region of integration is obviously the triangle given by the inequalities:
$$
0\le s \le t \qquad \qquad 0\le r \le s
$$
or equivalently:
$$
0\le r \le t \qquad \qquad r\le s \le t
$$
so swapping variables yields:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t)&= \int_0^t \int_r^t f(x-ct+2cs-cr,r) \,ds\, dr
\end{aligned}
$$
Now change $y=x-ct+2cs-cr$, and $dy=2c\, ds$ to obtain$^*$:
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t)&= \frac{1}{2c}\int_0^t \int_{x-ct+cr}^{x+ct-cr} f(y,r) \,dy\, dr
\end{aligned}
which is the required result under suitable variable renaming.

$^*$ Strictly speaking you have to change both variables and write the determinant of the jacobian of the transformation, so there is here some handwaving, that gives the same result though.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting the definition of $v$ into the definition of $u$ we have

\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_0^sf\big((x-ct+cs)+cs-cr,r\big)\,dr \right)\,ds\\
&=\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_0^sf\big(x+2cs-ct-cr,r\big)\,dr \right)\,ds
\end{align}

where we merely chose the letter $r$ to represent the variable of integration, rather than $s$. Now, let's change the order of integration:

\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_r^tf\big(x+2cs-ct-cr,r\big)\,ds \right)\,dr
\end{align}

Finally, for the inner integral, we use the substitution $y=x+2cs-ct-cr$, so $dy=2c\,ds$. Hence:

$$\int_r^tf\big(x+2cs-ct-cr,r\big)\,ds=\frac1{2c}\int_{x+cr-ct}^{x+ct-cr}f\big(y,r\big)\,dy,$$

so that

\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\frac1{2c}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{x+cr-ct}^{x+ct-cr}f\big(y,r\big)\,dy \,dr.
\end{align}

To get the desired answer, it suffices to change the letter $r$ that represents the variable of integration of the outer integral to $s$.